# Pandas: calculate column using previous rows

Tags: pandas

I have this code (no so good), calculating one column based on previous rows values by iterating :

```
date_prev_list= np.zeros(len(df))
for ii, row in df.iterrows():
   col_nb= row['colum_nb']
   if col_nb == col_nb_prev :    #Condition

      #Store previous row value in current row
      date_prev_list[ii]= date_prev

      #Store previous values
      date_prev=          row['datesec2']
      col_nb_prev=        col_nb

   else :
      #Store previous value 
      date_prev=    row['datesec2']
      col_nb_prev=  col_nb        

df['datesec_prev']=  pd.Series(  date_prev_list)
```

Just wondering if we can do directly with df.apply() in Pandas, using generic method.

Comment: Sample data / output?

Comment: Do you must use `df.apply`?

Comment: whatever things which is more pandas style (other than loop...).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution using `df.apply`, but this may help you.

Make sample data

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,2,2,3], 'b': [11,12,13,14,15]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   a   b
0  1  11
1  1  12
2  2  13
3  2  14
4  3  15
```

Solution:

```
In [6]: t = df.a.shift() == df.a

In [10]: df.b.shift().where(t, 0)
Out[10]:
0     0.0
1    11.0
2     0.0
3    13.0
4     0.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

Comment: am looking for general solutions, using other than loop.

Comment: @Tensor This is more pandas style although it's not as general as you expected.